# Twig - Do not interpret

Tags: twig

I'm looking for a tag which would enable me to stop interpreting in a section, in a template.

So I'm looking for something that is similar to smarty's literal tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I think you're looking for `{% verbatim %}` / `{% endverbatim %}`. In earlier versions these were called `{% raw %}` / `{% endraw %}`.

See also [Twig Escaping](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html#escaping).

Comment: That was renamed to `{% verbatim %}` in 1.12 to avoid confusion with the raw filter.

Answer (score 6):

In Twig, it is now verbatim, see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html